# C# IAsyncResult WaitAll

Tags: c#, iasyncresult

In some of the implementations of WaitAll I have seen the following code

```
IAsyncResult result1 = Method.BeginInvoke(10, MyCallback, null)
IAsyncResult result2 = Method.BeginInvoke(20, MyCallback, null)
WaitHandle[] waitHandles = new WaitHandle[] { result1.AsyncWaitHandle, result2.AsyncWaitHandle};
WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles)
```

Does this seem right ? What are the chances that before the waitHandles array is created one of the calls complete ?

Regards,
Dhananjay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Makes sense to me.

```
// Begin invoking the first and second method, and give them a callback
IAsyncResult result1 = Method.BeginInvoke(10, MyCallback, null)
IAsyncResult result2 = Method.BeginInvoke(20, MyCallback, null)

// Any time past the point of invokation, MyCallback could be called.
// Get the wait handles of the async results, regardless of whether they have finished or not
WaitHandle[] waitHandles = new WaitHandle[] { result1.AsyncWaitHandle, result2.AsyncWaitHandle};

// Make sure to wait until the methods have finished.
// They could have finished immediately, and MyCallback could have already been called,
// but we will never get past this line unless they have finished.
WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles)
// We may have waited on the function to finish, or they may have been done before we arrived at the previous line. Either way, they are done now.
```

What exactly do you find odd?

Asking "what are the chances" is a bad sign. The chances are *it might happen* which means you will need to account for what the program needs to do if and when the methods complete before you WaitAll.

Comment: The reason is  var result = del.EndInvoke(ar);

Comment: EndInvoke also waits for the async result to end, but the callback could have still been called before reaching EndInvoke.