# Not able to use Delegate and other functions

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, callback, delegates

I am calling a method by using delegates and the target function calls a callback once it is complete. However I do want to wait till its callback is called so that I can get the data.

For example:

```
//setup 

public IAsyncResult BeginGetTies(Request request, AsyncCallback cb, object asyncState)
{
     _service.GetTiesCompleted += Callback;
    _gets = new getTimeSeriesData(GetTies);

    IAsyncResult r = _gets.BeginInvoke(request, cb, asyncState);

    return r;
}

private void GetTies(Request request)
{
    _service.GetTies(tsr, id);
}

private void Callback(object sender, event e)
{
    // this gets called after EndGet 
}
```

Now this `_service.GetTies` uses a callback with events. However I get the control back when `_service.GetTies` calls gets completed. After that the callback is invoked. I want to wait till the callback gets invoked so that I can use the results.

Please help.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Interesting.  So you want the call back but not the asynchronous aspect?  Why not just call the function directly?

Comment: I want to use both. The problem is that the EndGet gets called as soon as GetTies is complete, but the data comes in Callback. If I cant resolve this then I will use synchronous model but I do want to find a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using [WaitHandles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629811/c-sharp-iasyncresult-waitall) should get you the desired results.

```
IAsyncResult result1 = Method.BeginInvoke(10, MyCallback, null)
result1.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();  // blocks until finished
```